# Schema.org type for web hosting company

Tags: hosting, schema.org

What Schema.org type should I use for a web hosting company?

Here is a [list of types provided by Schema.org](https://schema.org/docs/full.html), but I can't figure out which is best. `Product`?

Answer (score 0):

Start at [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing) and choose more-specific types until it’s no longer possible. The first match would be [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization). Then maybe [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness). There doesn’t appear to be a suitable `LocalBusiness` sub-type.

So if the web hosting company is a business with a physical location, you’d use [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) to represent it.

For the services/products this company offers, you’d use [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer), [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) and/or [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product).